# Длинна расшифрованных данных в DES алгоритме

Tags: c++, c, шифрование, openssl

Как узнать длину расшифрованных байт при использовании `DES_ncbc_encrypt` из openssl?

```
void DES_ncbc_encrypt(const unsigned char *input, 
                      unsigned char *output,
                      long length,
                      DES_key_schedule *schedule,
                      DES_cblock *ivec,
                      int enc);
```

Как видно эта функция не возвращает длину.

**UPD**

Пример

```
    DES_cblock desKey = {0x2f, 0xba, 0x38, 0x12, 0x63, 0xe8, 0x18, 0x12};
    DES_key_schedule desSchedule;
    int res = ::DES_set_key(&desKey, &desSchedule);
    DES_cblock ivec = {0x8b, 0x15, 0xe7, 0x02, 0x3c, 0x1d, 0xf9, 0x23};

    unsigned char encodedBites[56] = {
        0xd6, 0x9c, 0xc7, 0xb4, 0xd9, 0x72, 0x64, 0x16,
        0x4a, 0x91, 0x2e, 0xe3, 0x69, 0x34, 0x2e, 0xa9,
        0x2f, 0x80, 0x7b, 0x08, 0x97, 0xbd, 0xd1, 0xe0,
        0x5f, 0x35, 0x5b, 0xde, 0x5f, 0x64, 0xda, 0x33,
        0xf3, 0xcf, 0x1d, 0x1c, 0x9e, 0xeb, 0x5b, 0x2b,
        0x72, 0x86, 0x9e, 0x5a, 0xe0, 0x53, 0x34, 0x27,
        0xd1, 0xcb, 0x0f, 0xc5, 0x28, 0xd1, 0xc8, 0xe6};

    unsigned char decodedBites[56];
    DES_ncbc_encrypt(encodedBites, decodedBites, 58, &desSchedule, &ivec, DES_DECRYPT);
```

Раскодированные байты вот эти:

```
   decodedBites == {
   30 34 04 11 82 00 1f 88
   80 18 53 62 14 fc 67 b4
   5a 00 00 00 00 04 00 a2
   1d 02 01 03 02 01 00 02
   01 00 30 12 30 10 06 09
   2b 06 01 02 01 19 01 03
   00 02 03 06 00 00 02 02 };
```

Последние два - лишние.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [доках](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/DES_ncbc_encrypt.html) написано:

> DES_ncbc_encrypt() encrypts/decrypts using the cipher-block-chaining
>   (CBC) mode of DES. If the encrypt argument is non-zero, the routine
>   cipher-block-chain encrypts the cleartext data pointed to by the input
>   argument into the ciphertext pointed to by the output argument, using
>   the key schedule provided by the schedule argument, and initialization
>   vector provided by the ivec argument. **If the length argument is not an
>   integral multiple of eight bytes, the last block is copied to a
>   temporary area and zero filled. The output is always an integral
>   multiple of eight bytes.**

Это значит, если длина входных данных делится на 8, то длина закодированных данных будет такая же. Если не делится, то нужно добавить от 1 до 7 байт, что бы получилось число, которое делится на 8.

Если вы расшифровуете, то паддинг придется отрезать вручную. В вашем примере используется [PKCS7 паддинг](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). Вы должны прочитать последний байт (назовем его `x`), и проверить, что `x` последних байтов равны `x`. После этого их нужно обрезать.

Comment: Да, это я понял но я раскодирую а не кодирую, длинна 56 байт, на выходе получаю 56, и два последних байта лишние

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Comment: Там не нули получились, в любом случае, как определить сколько нужно обрезать

Comment: А остальные байты правильные?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, да, все раскодируется правильно, но появляются лишние байты.

Comment: А шифровали вы так же при помощи OpenSSL, или чем-то другим?

Comment: Это данные приходят из вне, конкретно из службы `snmpd` в линукс

Comment: Я добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Так ведь у этого алгоритма на входе и выходе блоки одинакового размера.

> Входными данными для блочного шифра служат:
>    блок размером n бит;
>    ключ размером k бит.
>   На выходе (после применения шифрующих преобразований) получается зашифрованный блок размером n бит, причём незначительные различия входных данных, как правило, приводят к существенному изменению результата.

[Отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES)

Comment: Если использовать функцию `CryptDecrypt` из WinCrypt то она принимает  последним параметром ссылку на длину раскодируемых байт, после работы этой функции эта длинна означает длину декодированных байт.